# how can i use loop for in tableView swift

Tags: swift, loops, tableview

How can i use for loop inside cellForItemAtIndexPath

here is my code , any help ?

i want return cell for each loop

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell:CellCollectionView = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellCollectionView
    for Restaurent1 in Resturent.Restaurants
    {
        var ResturentName = eachRestaurent.name
        var ResturentDescrption = eachRestaurent.descrption
        var ResturentId = eachRestaurent.id

        cell.ResturentsName.text = ResturentName
        cell.ResturentsDescrption.text = ResturentDescrption
        cell.ResturentsId.text = String(ResturentId as! Int)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You have 2 spellings of `Restaurant` in there, neither of which are correct...

Comment: in my code is not , i wrote an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use a loop in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. The loop is already built into Cocoa, which calls your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` implementation for each cell that it needs to render.

This API follows a "pull" model, instead of a "push". Table view "pulls" the data from your code when it needs to, instead of your code "pushing" all the data into the API at once. The advantage of this approach is that "pull" API will not call you back more times than is needed. For example, if only four restaurants from a list of 100 are visible, your method would be called four times, not 100.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell:CellCollectionView = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellCollectionView
    let r = esturent.Restaurants[indexPath.row]
    cell.ResturentsName.text = r.name
    cell.ResturentsDescrption.text = r.descrption
    cell.ResturentsId.text = String(r.id as! Int)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot , you solved the Biggest issue for me :) :)

Comment: @bsm-2000 You are welcome! Although this particular part of Cocoa API is not intuitive, it is easy to learn: once you do it once or twice, you start following it naturally, perhaps even structuring your own application for the "pull"-style API.

Comment: @bsm-2000 Hi! If this solution worked for you then would you please accept it as the correct answer.